# How to go back to first command prompt and close it in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bat file in which I call a couple of bat command sequentially:

start cmd /c a.bat

call b.bat

The 1st line will run a.bat in a new prompt window, after the 2nd line finish run, I want to go back to the window started from 1st line and close it, how can I achieve that? I need to start a.bat in a different window, since b.bat rely on it to run, I have tried

call a.bat

call b.bat

but it never starts b.bat since a.bat starts a server and just wait. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: this is very unclear. perhaps better describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: have you tried a WMIC win32_process create method.  That might get your server.exe started asynchronously avoiding the need for a.bat in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and inside `a.bat` start the server with `start "" "c:\program files\folder\server.exe"` so it will launch and return control to the `a.bat` and continue.

```
call a.bat
call b.bat
```